# Comparator operator in weak_ptr C++

Tags: c++, stl, c++11, weak-ptr

I am still a novice in the new stl members.Can anyone point out why this code is giving segmentation fault?

```
#include<memory>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<map>
#include<set>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
struct StubClass
{
    weak_ptr<string> b;
    int c;
    friend bool operator==(StubClass x,StubClass y);
    friend bool operator<(StubClass x,StubClass y);
    StubClass(weak_ptr<string> x):b(x){c=5;}    
};
bool operator==(StubClass d,StubClass c) { return d.b==c.b;}
bool operator<(StubClass d,StubClass c) { return d.b<c.b; }


int main()
{
    shared_ptr<string> spPtr(new string("Hello"));
    weak_ptr<string> wpPtr(spPtr);
    StubClass hello(wpPtr);
    set<StubClass> helloSet;
    helloSet.insert(hello);
    if(helloSet.find(StubClass(wpPtr))!=helloSet.end()) printf("YAYA");
    else puts("Bye");
}
```

The error is in line

> if(helloSet.find(StubClass(wpPtr))!=helloSet.end()) printf("YAYA");

More research reveals there is a problem when the StubClass's comparator function is called.
I am compiling the program [here](http://ideone.com/1uT0s)

EDIT:

```
bool operator==(StubClass d,StubClass c) { return d.b.lock()==c.b.lock();}
bool operator<(StubClass d,StubClass c) { return d.b.lock()<c.b.lock(); }
```

This resolved the issue.I should be reading more.:(
Anyways can anyone from the community explain the reason why the first code gives SIGSEGV.I figured it out eventually,but still a nice explanation won't hurt. :)

Comment: To ward off problems like this in the future it may be helpful to use explicit. `explicit StubClass(weak_ptr<string> x):b(x){c=5;}` would have revealed the problem right away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to compare strings stored in weak_ptr do this:

```
bool operator<(StubClass d, StubClass c) 
{
    std::shared_ptr<std::string> a = d.b.lock();
    std::shared_ptr<std::string> b = c.b.lock();

    if (!a && !b)
        return false; 

    if (!a)
        return true;

    if (!b)
        return false;

    return *a < *b;
}
```

[Run result](http://ideone.com/9R33N)

Comment: But if they are both `NULL`, you'll return `true`. I think it should be `false`.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late comment but why you return `true` when `a == nullptr` and `false` when `b == nullptr`?

Answer (score 5):

Your original code segfaults because you've accidentally set up an infinite recursion:

```
bool operator<(StubClass d,StubClass c) { return d.b<c.b; }
```

There is no `operator<` for `weak_ptr`.  However you do have an implicit conversion from `weak_ptr` to `StubClass`.  And `StubClass` has an `operator<`.  So this function calls itself indefinitely:  thus the segfault.

The currently accepted answer from inkooboo will also lead to undefined behavior, probably resulting in a crash.  As `weak_ptrs` become expired during the execution of your program (something more involved than your test case), then the ordering of them will change.  When this happens between two `weak_ptrs` in the `set`, the `set` will become corrupted, likely leading to a crash.  However there is a way around this using `owner_less` which was designed specifically for this use case:

```
bool operator==(const StubClass& d, const StubClass& c)
{
    return !owner_less<weak_ptr<string>>()(d.b, c.b) &&
           !owner_less<weak_ptr<string>>()(c.b, d.b);
}
bool operator<(const StubClass& d, const StubClass& c)
{
    return owner_less<weak_ptr<string>>()(d.b, c.b);
}
```

Or, if you prefer, this can also be coded using the member function `owner_before`.  Both are equivalent:

```
bool operator==(const StubClass& d, const StubClass& c)
{
    return !d.b.owner_before(c.b) && !c.b.owner_before(d.b);
}
bool operator<(const StubClass& d, const StubClass& c)
{
    return d.b.owner_before(c.b);
}
```

Using these functions, even when one `weak_ptr` expires and the other doesn't, their ordering remains stable.  And thus you'll have a well-defined `set`.

Comment: Interesting. Didn't know about owner-based comparison for smart pointers. In your solution the addresses of owner objects are comparing but not the key strings. I'm not sure that it is correct solution for @bashrc. By the way, for this code it looks like set could become corrupted in your solution too, when shared_ptr that owns string for keys become outdated.

Comment: When a weak_ptr expires (the last shared_ptr releases ownership), this comparison **does not change**.  The weak_ptr continues to compare **exactly the same** to other weak_ptrs.  This is because the control block to which the weak_ptr refers does not get deallocated until the last *weak_ptr* is destructed/reset/reassigned.